# sqlsrv_prepare error with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and ZF2

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, zend-framework2

I followed the excellent tutorial of Rob Allen with ZF2 (http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework-2.pdf).

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008. And when i'm doing

```
$this->getDatasTable()->fetchAll()
```

I'm getting the folloing error:

```
PHP Warning:  sqlsrv_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LinuxWebApp\source\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Sqlsrv\Statement.php on line 153
```

In config/autoload/global.php I have:

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver' => 'Sqlsrv',
    'dsn'            => 'sqlsrv:dbname=xxx;hostname=xxx',
    'username'       => 'xxx',
    'password'       => 'xxx',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
);
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` won't work for SQL Server. Try removing the `driver_options` section.

Update with next idea:
Parameter 1 is the sqlsrv resource, so can you get a test script working that uses the PDO Sqlsrv driver directly? I'm currently wondering if there's a problem with connection.

Comment: Hey Rob! I updated to ZF2 beta5, removed the `driver_options` section and I still get the same error message.